# Scheme Question - How can I check if there are a list of pairs

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

So I need to write code on scheme that checks if there is a list of pairs? Any ideas on where to get started?

```lisp
  (define (list-of-pairs? lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        #f
        (if (pair? (cdr lst))
            #t
            (list-of-pairs? (cddr lst)))))
```

and I have no idea where to go from here if that is even correct

I know this is wrong as I get this error

list-of-pairs?: arity mismatch;
the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
expected: 1
given: 4
arguments...:

when i input this

```lisp
(list-of pairs?
   (list
   (cons 1 (cons 2 empty))
   (cons 2 (cons null empty))
   (cons 3 (cons 4 (list 4 5 6))))
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you expect your function to do. Do you want it to return `#t` iff the passed argument is a list of pair? Or to you want it to return `#t` iff the passed argument **contains** a list of pair (which your formulation "if there are a list of pairs" seems to indicate. Tho, I am not an English native speaker, so I may be wrong here)?

Comment: As for your immediate error (but once you'll have corrected it, I doubt it would work as expected too, whatever you expect), it is simple: your function needs one argument (a list, obviously); and you called it with 4 arguments: `list` (the function `list`, not A list), `(cons 1 (cons 2 empty))` (whatever `empty` is. It is nothing predefined on my interpreter), `(cons 2 (cons null empty))` (same remark for `null` and `empty`), and `(cons 3 (cons 4 (list 4 5 6)))` aka the list `(3 4 4 5 6)`.

Comment: You obviously meant to call it with a list containing the 3 last arguments. That is to call it with `(list (cons 1 (cons 2 empty)) (cons 2 (cons null empty)) (cons 3 (cons 4 (list 4 5 6))))` (with still the same remark for `empty` and `null`). So, to call the function `list` with the 3 arguments, and then call your function from the result of `(list ...)`

Comment: sorry I made an edit 

It is supposed to check whether the list contains pairs

Comment: You also have a dash `-` missing: `list-of-pair?` not `list-of pair?`. But now that you have corrected the *« `(list ...)` not `list ...` »* error, I guess the error mesrage has changed.

Comment: The question is still not clear to me. `(1 2 3 "hello" (4 5 6) (7 . 8) 9 10)` contains a pair (the pair `(7.8)`), among may non-pair things (numbers such as `1`, `2`, string such as `"hello"`, and a sublist `(4 5 6)` — which, technically, is also a pair, since `(4 5 6)` is another way to write `(4 . ( 5 . (6 . ())))`). So, should your function return `#t` in such a case? Or should it return `#t` only when the argument list contains only pairs, and nothing else?

Comment: Your code is wrong off the bat because the empty list `null?` is a list of pairs. It is a vacuous truth that an empty list contains nothing but pairs, which makes it a list of pairs.  So in that case you want to return `#t`.  By returning `#f`, we are testing for a non-empty list of pairs.

Comment: If you look at just about any example of list traversal, you will find that they use `car` and `cdr` (or `first` and `rest`), not `cdr` and `cddr`.

Answer (score 0):

*"I know this is wrong as I get this error."* This arity mismatch error has nothing to do with the posted code. Rather, it seems that OP has experienced the result of some typo in testing the defined procedure. The posted test contains at least two typos: `list-of pairs?` is missing a hyphen, and the entire expression is missing a closing parenth; this leads me to believe that OP has typed the expression into the body of the question instead of copy-pasting. If this were the actual testing expression the error would probably be more along the lines of ***list-of undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition***.

As a side note, this code contains `empty` and `null` which are not defined in Standard Scheme; it looks like OP is actually writing Racket, but this doesn't substantially change the answer to OP's question.

### Problems With the Posted Code

The OP definition for `list-of-pairs?` is incorrect. To see why, let's look at a few input examples:

```
> (list-of-pairs? '())
#f
> (list-of-pairs? '(1))
cddr: contract violation
  expected: (cons/c any/c pair?)
  given: '(1)
 [,bt for context]
> (list-of-pairs? '(1 2))
#t
```

To start, when the input is the empty list, OP's procedure returns `#f`. Ordinarily I would expect this case to yield `#t`, since an empty list is an empty list of pairs, and of any other type you could think of. By itself this isn't a deal breaker, and the procedure could be sensibly written to return `#f` in such cases.

More serious problems become evident for the next two cases. When the input is a list containing a single integer, I would expect the procedure to yield `#f`, but instead the result is an error. Why? The list `(1)` is not empty, so the OP procedure goes on to check whether the `cdr` of `(1)` is a pair; but the `cdr` of `(1)` is `()`, and `(pair? '())` is `#f`, so finally the OP procedure checks whether the `cddr` of `(1)` is a `list-of-pairs?`. But, `(cddr '(1))` is undefined in Scheme (and in Racket). Expanding this call shows: `(cddr '(1))` -> `(cdr (cdr '(1)))` -> `(cdr '())` -> *error!*

Further, when the input is a list of integers the OP procedure unexpectedly returns `#t`. This can't be right because an integer is not a pair, and a list of integers is surely not a list of pairs. What is happening here? When the input is `(1 2)` it is not empty, and the `cdr` of `(1 2)` is `(2)`, which is in fact a pair because *every* list is a pair! Specifically, every list is a pair comprised of a `car` part and a `cdr` part. So in this case the expression `(if (pair? (cdr lst)) ;...` returns `#t`. But we don't want to know if the `cdr` of the input is a pair; we want to know if the `car` of the input is a pair (which OP code never checks), and whether the other elements of the list are also pairs.

A fundamental problem here is that the OP procedure is taking its list input apart incorrectly for the needs of the problem.

### One Solution

To solve a problem recursively you always need to identify at least two things: what is the base case, and what is the recursive step. The base case is a simple case for which the answer can be immediately found. The recursive step works to reduce the input case *towards* the base case in some way. Ordinarily you need to *combine* the results of each recursive call in some way.

Sometimes it is helpful to describe what we want (in this case to describe what constitutes a `list-of-pairs?`): a `list-of-pairs?` is an empty list, or a list for which the first element is a pair, and the remainder of the list is a `list-of-pairs?`.

Here, the base case is when the input is the empty list. In that case, let's say that the result should be `#t`, that is, an empty list is an empty list of pairs. When the input is a nonempty list, how can it be reduced towards the base case? If the *first* element of the input is not a pair, we are done because the input is not a list of pairs. But, if the first element *is* a pair, then we need to combine this knowledge with the knowledge about the rest of the input list. That is, if the `car` of the input is a pair, and if the rest of the input is a `list-of-pairs?`, then the input is a list of pairs. Here the list given to recursive calls of `list-of-pairs?` has been reduced *towards the base case* by using `cdr`. Here is that solution:

```lisp
(define (list-of-pairs? xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      #t
      (and (pair? (car xs))
           (list-of-pairs? (cdr xs)))))
```

Knowledge of the first element of the input and the status of the remainder of the list is combined using the `and` operator. When the first element (of any recursive call) is not a pair, `#f` is returned and combined with any previous `#t` values to yield `#f`. Otherwise `#t` is returned.

If it is desired that the empty list should *not* be a list of pairs, the above can be adjusted with a bit of thought, but I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: A more literal translation of your informal spec would use `(or (null? xs) ...)` instead of `(if (null? xs) #t ...)`. "A `list-of-pairs?` is an empty list, **or** ..."

Comment: @amalloy -- I considered that, but felt like it obscured the base case a bit. I'm on the fence about it; maybe I shouldn't have written that description in a more declarative style.